# jquery ui multiselect plugin does not let me drag drop consistently

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, multi-select

I am using jQuery ui.multiselect.js plugin to order columns in my jqGrid. I have noticed that there are some inconsistencies in the way this plugin behaves. It lets me drag-n-drop from right column to left but not left to right column. Has anyone got a working solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is exactly a problem, it is the way the plugin is supposed to work if you set the option `sortable: true` which is the default:

- you can drag column from right list to left to choose which ones you'd like to show in the grid
- you can re-order the column on the left list to change the order they appear in the grid

Setting the option `sortable` to false cancels both these behaviors, you cannot drag to add and sort columns order anymore.

Answer (score 0):

ui.multiselect.js has been updated since this post, and it now allows you to drag from left to right as well. It also allows you to load data from an external source now. [You can check it out here.](http://quasipartikel.at/multiselect_next/)